# excel networkdays sum over range

Tags: excel-formula

Goal:I'm looking to calculate the sum of the elapsed work days between two columns on sheet1 for use in a formula that returns average time elapsed on sheet2.

Rule 1: I can't add columns to sheet1, so I'd ideally like to do this entirely in a formula on sheet2.

So far, I know that you can use =NETWORKDAYS(Cell1,Cell2) to do this on an individual basis, but that voids rule 1 where I can't add columns. I also know that I can use =SUM(NETWORKDAYS(O5+1,P5),NETWORKDAYS(O6+1,P6)), but I'd rather define a range instead of each cell.

Ideally, I'd like to take the result of the sum of networking days and divide that by a separate variable with the same range to get time per variable in that range. Any help on making this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Sheet2!R4 cell is empty.. do :

In Sheet2!O5 , put `=Sheet1!O5` . Then in Sheet2!P5 , put `=Sheet1!P5` . drag downwards 
to get all Sheet1 dates.

Then in Sheet2!Q5 put `=NETWORKDAYS(O5+1,P5)` . and in Sheet2!R5 put `=R4+Q5` . And drag both downwards.. the last column R value is equivalent to the

> =SUM(NETWORKDAYS(O5+1,P5),NETWORKDAYS(O6+1,P6))

you've mentioned. Hope it helps.